# Debounce timer not restarting when input is changed

Tags: r, shiny, debouncing

I am trying to create a date input that automatically updates the inputted value to the end of the selected month. The problem I was having was when I ran this first bit of code (below) was that if the user tries to manually change the date by typing in a date, they are unable to because the input is updated instantly to the end of the month before the user can finish typing.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    dateInput(
      inputId = "date", 
      label = "End of Month Date", 
      value = ceiling_date(x = Sys.Date() + 365, unit = "month") - 1, 
      startview = "year"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(is.Date(input$date) & length(input$date) > 0){
      if(input$date != ceiling_date(input$date, unit = "month") - 1) {
        updateDateInput(
          session, 
          inputId = "date",
          value = ceiling_date(x = input$date, unit = "month") - 1
        )
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So, I tried implementing debounce (as shown below - server code change only) so that it would delay the input from updating until the user was finished typing; however, I am running into an issue. The timer does not reset on each key stroke as I understand it should. Instead, the timer operates as if I were using the throttle function and starts when the input is first changed and doesn't reset when the input changes.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    dateinputdelay <- debounce(r = reactive(input$date), millis = 2000)
    if(is.Date(dateinputdelay()) & length(dateinputdelay()) > 0){
      if(dateinputdelay() != ceiling_date(dateinputdelay(), unit = "month") - 1) {
        updateDateInput(
          session, 
          inputId = "date",
          value = ceiling_date(x = input$date, unit = "month") - 1
        )
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Your `observe` block is going to be triggered frequently because `input$date` is within its expression, regardless of the immediately-surrounding (but still nested-with `debounce`). I suggest you put `foo=debounce(reactive(...))` outside of your `observe` block, then do `dateinputdelay<-foo()` within.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: the best I can get is with the code below, but because the "fancy date input thingy" has its own internal updating mechanism separate from shiny's `reactive` concept, this debouncing is only addressing one source of problem.

The first trick is that the `debounce` needs to happen *before* the block of code is even started. That is, it "de-bounces" the start of the dependent code blocks; once they are started, it does not help.

The second is knowing that `observe` blocks attempt to run their code *eagerly* (see [shiny docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/observe.html) and read "Details"), whereas `reactive` blocks are relatively *lazy* -- they only run dependent code as needed. It's the "eager" part that may be hurting.

Additionally, you use side-effect in the `observe` block to update the input field, but you never store the value elsewhere. I suggest that it might be better to calculate the new value in one place (in a *functional* manner, like a `reactive` block that should *not* operate in side-effect) and then use that later.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dateinputdelay <- debounce(reactive(input$date), 2000)
  end_of_month <- reactive({
    # print("react!")
    x <- dateinputdelay()
    if (is.Date(x) & length(x) > 0) {
      if (x != ceiling_date(x, unit = "month") - 1) {
        x <- ceiling_date(x = input$date, unit = "month") - 1
      }
    }
    x
  })
  observe({
    # print("observe!")
    updateDateInput(
      session, 
      inputId = "date",
      value = end_of_month()
    )
  })
}
```

(I've kept a couple of `print` statements in there, not because they help much here, but because they can be a good tool to see when/how-frequently reactitivity is causing code-blocks to run.)

As I said up top, I suspect this behavior is indicative of something within `dateInput`, not within the subsequent `reactive` or `observe` blocks.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I get the same result after moving the debounce outside of the observe block as shown above. I can't finish typing the date before it resets.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what is complicating this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up limiting the Date Input.